# Angular app deployed together with Spring Boot backend do not work

Tags: javascript, java, spring, angular, spring-boot

I have a problem with putting my app in motion. It is Spring boot back end + Angular5 front end. They work separately without issues but it stops when I put angular app (dist contents) into Spring public location.
Every tutorial I read says it should work out of the box but it doesn't. 
Basically, the index page is complaining about lack of generated javascript files (although they are located in the same dir as index page), they simply cannot be found (404).

I'm completely lost, everything looks correct for me, what I am doing wrong here,

Comment: Is your Spring Boot application standalone or you deploy it in some web container?

Comment: deployed to WebLogic 12c
however front-end cannot find js fiels even if I run it in the browser from file (by doubleclick on index.html)

Comment: Where are you putting your angular's files? You have to located it in your static folder, inside the resources directory. Another thing you should see it's if you have configured spring security you have to see your WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and permit all request to your .js files.

It should be awesome if you share a little of your code with us.

Comment: I tried both /resources/public and static with no success.
Posting whole code is not an option, which part you'd like to see?

Comment: In terms of security I have it indeed and the only rule I have right now is:
 http.csrf().disable() // for developemnt purpose only, should be removed when deployed to upper levels
            .anonymous()
            .and()
            //.addFilter(preAuthFilter())
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**").permitAll();